# Best way to convert called OSM data from SF to Shapefile within R

Tags: r, gis, openstreetmap, r-sf, rgdal

Completely new to R, forgive me -

I'm trying to use R to create some historic OSM data thats stored as a `sf` (simple feature) within the R script. I'd like to export this data once called as a shapefile (or GEOJSON) readable by QGIS. The reason I am doing this is that it seems to me that extracting specific historic datasets via Rs `osmdata` package is the most efficient way of creating data of specific segments of OSM historic data for a given period in its editing history (Let me know if anyone have a faster way of doing this for country-sized batches of data for different years.)

My current code, using a sample dataset, looks like this:

```
library(osmdata)

library(sf)

q1 <- opq('Sevilla') %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = 'cycleway')
cway_sev <- osmdata_sp(q1)
sp::plot(cway_sev$osm_lines)
```

I'm getting two different types of errors:

When I add a specific datetime (like this: `q1 <- opq('Sevilla',datetime = "2015-01-01T12:00:00Z") %>%`), I'm getting this error:

```
Error in check_for_error(doc) : General overpass server error; returned:
The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL. runtime error: Query timed out in "query" at line 4 after 45 seconds.
```

Additionally, and I'm guessing more improtantly, when I add the [function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html) to convert from an SF to a SHP
(`st_write(cway_sev, "sev_t_1.shp")`)

I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_write") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "c('list', 'osmdata', 'osmdata_sp')"
```

Any advice? Again, complete R newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not help you with the timeout on a historic `datetime`; there may be a server side issue for all that I know (I get the same error, and your construction of the argument seems to follow documentation).

Regarding the other issues:

When working in the world of `{sf}` I suggest to download your data via `osmdata_sf()` call; it will be good for your sanity if you avoid mixing `sf` and `sp` worlds unless absolutely necessary.

The returned object will contain not only lines, but also points, polygons and (in your case empty) multi-type objects.

When working with cycle paths just select the `osm_lines` object to a new variable; it will contain Sevilla bike paths with geometry of type linestring.

After checking it visually you can now save it as a ESRI Shapefile; note that this is an ancient file format, based on Ashton Tate dBase IV (a DOS program for Pete's sake :) and as such allows data column names of only limited number of characters, hence the warning.

```
library(osmdata)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

sevilla <- opq('Sevilla') %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = 'cycleway') %>% 
  osmdata_sf()

names(sevilla) # note the points, polygons, multilines and multipolygons
# [1] "bbox"              "overpass_call"     "meta"              "osm_points"        "osm_lines"        
# [6] "osm_polygons"      "osm_multilines"    "osm_multipolygons"

# just a single geometry type
sevilla_lines <- sevilla$osm_lines

# visual check of lines geometry only / does this look right?
plot(st_geometry(sevilla_lines))
```

[image: Sevilla bike paths]

```
# this will work, with the lines only
st_write(sevilla_lines, "sevilla.shp")
# Writing layer `sevilla' to data source `sevilla.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
# Writing 555 features with 34 fields and geometry type Line String.
# Warning message:
# In abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj) :
#  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
```

Comment: thanks! Your code is giving me a strange error - at the [1] its saying " Error: unexpected '[' in "["

Comment: sorry, my fault! you are not supposed to copy the two lines below `names(sevilla)` - that is the output :) also the writing bla bla bla under `st_write()` is not a part of the code but the output.... I should have commented it out, sorry!